# Getting a link from emails using a dedicated account

Tags: python, xml, atom-feed

I've been writing automated tests for a web application and it involves sending emails not just for account creation and password resets, but as the premise for the actual product it sends emails with virtual documents.

As part of my tests I obviously need to check that these emails contain certain elements eg. link to sign up, link to documents etc.

I have written some python code (for the gmail atom feed) that would just find and print the title of each email and if their is a link print that too but it cannot find the link.

```
import urllib2
import untangle

FEED_URL = 'https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom'

def get_unread_msgs(user, passwd):
    auth_handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()
    auth_handler.add_password(
        realm='New mail feed',
        uri='https://mail.google.com',
        user='{user}@gmail.com'.format(user=user),
        passwd=passwd
    )

    opener = urllib2.build_opener(auth_handler)
    urllib2.install_opener(opener)
    feed = urllib2.urlopen(FEED_URL)
    return feed.read()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import getpass

    user = raw_input('Username: ')
    passwd = getpass.getpass('Password: ')
    xml = get_unread_msgs(user, passwd)
    o = untangle.parse(xml)

    try:
        for item in o.feed.entry:
            title = item.title.cdata
            print title
            link = item.link.cdata
            if link:
                print "Link"
                print '   ', link

    except IndexError:
        pass    # no new mail
```

**Edit:** I've just realised that the atom feed doesn't actually give the message data..

Could anyone please suggest an alternative method of achieving my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could access the messages via [`imaplib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imaplib.html#module-imaplib) instead:

```
import imaplib

def get_unread_msgs(user, passwd):
    M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
    M.login(user, passwd)
    try:
        M.select()
        try:
            type, data = M.search(None, '(UNSEEN)')
            for num in data[0].split():
                yield M.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
        finally:
            M.close()
    finally:
        M.logout()
```

You will need to enable IMAP in your gmail settings if you haven't already:

- [Get started with IMAP and POP3](https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/1668960?hl=en#ts=1665018)

Comment: The issue is that I need to wait until the email arrives, this is a smaller part of an automated test suite. I don't really want to do something horrible like make an inf loop and then repeat the code until an email eventually appears.

Any ideas on how I could apply this to my solution?

Comment: You'll note that that is exactly what every email client does... :)

Comment: I'm not sure which answer I'm going to use, but both are good. I will choose select the imap answer plainly because it's not as specific and future users will find it the most helpful (as I hope they will this comment)

Comment: *** Warning: *** If you're using this code from a corporate environment make sure that port 143 is unblocked as that is the port IMAP uses by default!

Comment: @Stormie Em, since it's IMAP over SSL, it should be 993 by default?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a (gmail specific) solution without polling the server for updates, you can look into the [Gmail Notifications](https://developers.google.com/talk/jep_extensions/gmail?csw=1) API.